# obiee 12c rpd tools utilities repository documentation to csv columns misaligned and presentation column is null

Tags: obiee

Currently using Obiee admin client tool 12C - version 12.2.1.3.0

When exporting RPD repository documentation using Obiee admin client tool under option `Tools-->Utilities..`, CSV report is not proper aligned or presentation column is NULL. I checked Oracle support and got to know that It is a BUG 29525962. Followed support solution and patch however no luck.

Steps tried:

- Tried exporting with 12.2.1.1.0, 12.2.1.3.0 & 12.2.1.4.0 admin tool however no luck
- Tried to save report using Tab Separated Values(*.txt)
- Downgrade RPD version to open RPD and export report using 11G Admin tool but result is same.

Appreciate any help on this please.

Answer (score 0):

If the patch doesn't solve the issue, then open a Service Request stating these facts with all details (precise version, host OS etc). An patch not doing its job must be reported and there normally isn't away around your problem since it requires a patch and is therefor a product defect in the first place.